# array_push key=>value , how can do it?

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

I want to push key and value in array , but I can't

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','wp') or die (mysqli_error('Error:'));

$query = mysqli_query($con,'set names utf8')or die (mysql_error());
$qy = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ID,post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type='page' AND post_status='publish'")or die (mysql_error());
$arr = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qy)){
$id = "?page_id=".$row['ID'];
$title = $row['post_title'];
$arr[] = $id . "=>" . $title;
array_push($arr, "$id" => "$title");  
}
```

plz help me ..

thanks ^_^

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using array_push() to add elements to an array in the form of 'key => object'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772314/using-array-push-to-add-elements-to-an-array-in-the-form-of-key-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I would do instead:

```
$arr = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qy)){
    $id = $row['ID'];
    $arr[$id] = $row['post_title'];
}
```

And then when you need to print them:

```
foreach ($arr as $id => $title) {
    echo "?page_id={$id}'>{$title}</a>";
    // or whatever, depends on how you want to print it
}
```

Don't store unnecessary information (ie: `?page_id=`) in arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to do `$arr[$id] = $title`?  Or do you want this:

```
if (!isSet($arr[$id])) {
    $arr[$id] = array();
}
$arr[$id][] = $title;
```

The former will make it so that `$arr` contains `$id=>$title`.  The latter will make it so that `$arr` contains `$id=>array($title1,$title2,$title3)` etc if there are multiples.

Comment: thank you very much , the result is fail ..
this is the result
$My_links = array('2' => 'Array' ,'4' => 'Array' ,'6' => 'Array' ,'9' => 'Array' ,'11' => 'Array' ,'13' => 'Array' ,'45' => 'Array' );

Comment: @AboSami: Yes, if you use the second bit of code, that *should* be the result.  If you use just `$arr[$id] = $title`, it will not, but your IDs had better be unique!