# Using array_push() to add elements to an array in the form of 'key => object'

Tags: php

I have a set of objects I want to put into an array and I want to distinguish them with keys.

The initial code I wrote was:

```
array_push($array[$key], new myObj(param1, param2, etc));
```

When I run it I get the warning:

```
PHP Warning:  array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in file.php on line 56
```

I added a var_dump() to see what was actually happening and it was filling the array with each element '$key => null'  as suggested by the error.

If I remove the [$key] from the line then it fills the array with instances of myObj as expected so I know that the constructor is functioning correctly and not really returning 'null'.

Comment: Not sure what the etiquette is here, but the wording on this question and its conciseness makes it far more readable/searchable than the candidate dupe. I'd prefer to make the old one a dupe of this one, honestly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keys in associative arrays need to be unique, so if you want to keep the notion of a key/value pair where you can access things directly by the key, don't use `array_push`, simply set the key (this is fine to do in PHP):

```
$array[$key] = new myObj(param1, param2, etc)
```

On the other hand, if you want to have a list of key/value pairs, like a stack, and you're adding just one key/value pair at a time, don't use `array_push`, simply add to the array using PHP's shorthand syntax ([as the manual says, this is faster as it saves you a function call](http://us.php.net/array_push)):

```
$stack[] = array($key => new myObj(param1, param2, etc));
```

One more possibility, if you have a bunch of key/value pairs, and you want to add all of them to some stack like structure (but not be able to index directly by some key), then you *should* use `array_push`:

```
array_push($stack,
    array($key1 => new myObj(param1, param2, etc)),
    array($key2 => new myObj(param3, param4, etc))
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!  I actually found the answer myself (here). I failed to do a search before posting.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481584/array-push-key-value-how-can-do-it

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$array[$key] = new myObj(param1, param2, etc);
```